# What does Visual Studio pass to it's ITagger.GetTags calls?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, mef

I'm trying to create some syntax highlighting in VS2010 for a custom file format. After stealing extensively from the [Ook! Language](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ookLanguage) example on msdn, I'm able to highlight the keywords in the file. I'm happy with this. However, that example splits the SnapshotSpans by Line. I'd also like to handle multi-line highlighting (e.g. comments).

After debugging through the calls to my defined GetTags method, it seems like the method gets called multiple times per file, but gets passed the same SnapshotSpan collection. And, since every character typed causes another series of calls, it because very difficult to process what exactly is getting passed to it. So what should I expect in that collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since anything can consume your tagger, there's no defined specification on what can be passed  to `GetTags`.  If you want to handle multi-line information, that's something your component will have to parse out itself, generally in response to text changes and, if it is expensive, on a background thread.

In most cases, where the consumer is an `IWpfTextView`, you can expect that collection to be a single line at a time.  If a single-line text change (like typing) would affect multiple lines, your tagger should raise `TagsChanged` over the region that needs to be updated.

The general model is described a bit in a [blog article I wrote about VS editor fundamentals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahric/archive/2010/07/08/editor-fundamentals-push-vs-pul.aspx).  The gist is that consumers of tagging information will ask about what they care about, and subscribe to change events from the tagger to make sure that whatever information they've collected is up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for you response. This is useful. However, I'm still a little confused on some points. First off, the Tagger classes in the Ook! example take a TextBuffer that never gets used. What is this buffer for? Secondly, your blog post makes it seem as if I can define spans. How exactly do I do that? If I don't, does the SpanCollection just consist of 1 span with the entire file in it? Thanks again for your help.